# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure - OOM Exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my application I'm scooping a table of 5million rows and 151 columns using spark partitioning like below and persisting it to DISK_ONLY

```
   val query = "(select * from destinationlarge) as dest"
val options = Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:mysql://IPADDRESS:3306/test?useSSL=false",
  "driver" -> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  "dbtable" -> query,
  "user" -> "root",
  "password" -> "root")

val destination = spark.read.options(options).jdbc(options("url"), options("dbtable"), "0", 1, 5, 4, new java.util.Properties()).rdd.map(_.mkString(",")).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
```

The cluster is having 5 datanodes and 1 namenode of hardware configuration i3 4 cores and 4 GB RAM each, after sometime of execution one of the executor is dead and throwing the below ERROR

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, datanode5, executor 6): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 6 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 139401 ms
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1965)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1158)
at com.syntel.spark.sparkDVT$.main(sparkDVT.scala:68)
at com.syntel.spark.sparkDVT.main(sparkDVT.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:750)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

`lowerbound=1`,`upperbound=5`,`number of partitions is 4` suggested in this link (https://www.dezyre.com/article/how-data-partitioning-in-spark-helps-achieve-more-parallelism/297) total number of cores is equal to number of partitions that is 4 cores in all the nodes so 4 partitions.

`spark-submit`

`spark-submit --class "com.syntel.spark.sparkDVT" --master yarn --jars --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 5 /root/sparkdvtmysql_2.11-1.0.jar`

Correct me if I'm wrong

Thanks

Comment: Is this all you're doing? `map` and `persist` are both transformations, not actions, and I'd expect no execution to happen.

Comment: @Tim, actually no I have set of operations like `val source_primary_key = source.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0), rec))
    source_primary_key.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
    val extra_in_source = source_primary_key.subtractByKey(destination_primary_key)
    var pureextinsrc = extra_in_source.count()
    extra_in_source.cache()`and so on but before this its throwing out of memory exception while im fetching the entire table from database, which is the best way to do where I can do partitioning keep the data in memory or I should persist() it to DISK

Comment: `(datanode5, executor 6): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 6 exited caused by one of the running tasks)`.. Have you verified executor 6 logs in datanode5 before confirming it's OOM Exception ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you use DataFame(in Spark 2.0 i.e DataSet[Row]) as is, because **DataSet uses Encoders so that it will have very little memory footprint than RDD**.

```
val destination = spark.read
    .options(options)
    .format("jdbc")
    .load()
```

If you want concat columns by delimiter you can use [concat_ws() - example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42025251/1592191)

```
destination
  .withColumn("column", concat_ws(", ", 
     destination.columns.map(destination.col(_)).toSeq : _*))
  .select("id, column") // id will be used for subtraction with other df
  .persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
```

Check [this SO post - Comaparing RDD/DF/DS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45253013/1592191) which you the idea of how Dataset diffrent from RDD and it's advantages.

This may not answer your question entirely. I will update the asnwer as per my comment response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156518/discussion-between-mrsrinivas-and-vignesh).